# Rake `directory` does not recursively create folders

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying out Rake today to build my project, coding along with [Jim Weirich's presentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20140221135938/http://www.onestepback.org/articles/buildingwithrake/directorydependencies.html). I have a task `create_directories`:

```
task :create_directories do
  directory('build/subfolder')
end
```

Now when I execute `rake create_directories`, it outputs `mkdir -p build` and the build folder is created, but not the subfolder. Why is the subfolder not created as well?

**directory**:

```
private instance method directory(*args, &block) in Rake::DSL in rake\dsl_definition.rb  

Documentation:
Declare a set of files tasks to create the given directories on demand.  
Example:    directory "testdata/doc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mkdir_p` in `FileUtils`

```
task :create_directories do
  FileUtils.mkdir_p 'build/subfolder'
end
```

[documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/mkdir_p)

HTH